# Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have made a simple Kotlin application called Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock. The application takes in user input and check if belongs to given set of array. If it belongs then it compares user input and random value from array to generate result. Else it prints error and asks for user input again. My code is working fine. Is it possible to simplify my code?

````
    fun getUserChoice(userChoice: Array<String>): String {

    var isValidChoice = false
    var userValue = ""
    while (!isValidChoice) {
        // Ask the user for their choice
        println("Please enter one of the following:")

        for ((index, item) in userChoice.withIndex()) {
            println("${index + 1} . $item")
        }
        val userInput = readLine().toString()
        println("You have chosen $userInput")

        // validate the user input
        if (userInput in userChoice
        ) {
            isValidChoice = true
            userValue = userInput
        } else (println(ERROR_MESSAGE))

        // If the choice is invalid inform the user
        if (!isValidChoice) {
            ERROR_MESSAGE


        }


    }
    return userValue

}


fun getGameChoice(randomChoice: String) = randomChoice

fun printResult(gamePrint: String, userPrint: String) {

    println("I have chosen $gamePrint")
    if (gamePrint == userPrint) {
        println("It is a draw")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Rock" && userPrint == "Paper") {
        println("$userPrint covers $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Lizard" && userPrint == "Paper") {
        println("$gamePrint eats $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Scissor" && userPrint == "Paper") {
        println("$gamePrint cuts $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Spock" && userPrint == "Paper") {
        println("$userPrint disproves $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Rock" && userPrint == "Scissor") {
        println("$userPrint crushes $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Rock" && userPrint == "Lizard") {
        println("$userPrint crushes $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Rock" && userPrint == "Spock") {
        println("$gamePrint vaporizes $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Paper" && userPrint == "Scissor") {
        println("$gamePrint cuts $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Spock" && userPrint == "Scissor") {
        println("$gamePrint smashes $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Lizard" && userPrint == "Scissor") {
        println("$userPrint cuts $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Paper" && userPrint == "Lizard") {
        println("$userPrint eats $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Spock" && userPrint == "Lizard") {
        println("$userPrint poisons $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Paper" && userPrint == "Spock") {
        println("$gamePrint disproves $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Scissor" && userPrint == "Lizard") {
        println("$gamePrint decapitates $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Scissor" && userPrint == "Spock") {
        println("$userPrint smashes $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Lizard" && userPrint == "Spock") {
        println("$gamePrint poisons $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Spock" && userPrint == "Rock") {
        println("$gamePrint vaporizes $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Paper" && userPrint == "Rock") {
        println("$gamePrint covers $userPrint. $gamePrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Lizard" && userPrint == "Rock") {
        println("$userPrint crushes $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else if (gamePrint == "Scissor" && userPrint == "Rock") {
        println("$userPrint crushes $gamePrint. $userPrint wins!!")
    } else (ERROR_MESSAGE)


}

const val ERROR_MESSAGE = "You must enter a valid choice"

fun main() {
    val choices = arrayOf("Rock", "Paper", "Scissor", "Lizard", "Spock")
    val gameChoice = getGameChoice(choices.random())
    val userChoice = getUserChoice(choices)
    printResult(gameChoice, userChoice)

}
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see repetitious code like your very long if/else statement, you can probably make it a lot simpler. In this case, you can create a collection to concisely store what beats what as a list of relationships. This is a lot more maintainable if you are debugging later or find that you need to modify something. Unfortunately, since the wheel of relationships is complicated, I can't think of a way to get the compiler to ensure we don't accidentally leave out a relationship.

I would start with defining an enum for the possible choices, and a list of all the possible comparisons. An enum is a natural choice when you have a finite, pre-defined set of choices. Now the compiler will catch if we make any typos typing the choice names anywhere, which is a risk when you are using them as String literals.

```
enum class Choice {
    Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock;
    companion object {
        val relationships = listOf(
            Relationship(Rock, Lizard, "crushes"),
            Relationship(Rock, Scissors, "crushes"),
            Relationship(Paper, Spock, "disproves"),
            Relationship(Paper, Rock, "covers"),
            Relationship(Scissors, Paper, "cuts"),
            Relationship(Scissors, Lizard, "decapitates"),
            Relationship(Spock, Rock, "vaporizes"),
            Relationship(Spock, Scissors, "smashes"),
            Relationship(Lizard, Paper, "eats"),
            Relationship(Lizard, Spock, "poisons")
        )
    }
}
data class Relationship(val winner: Choice, val loser: Choice, val means: String)
```

Now the `getUserChoice` function doesn't need a list passed to it. We just need to check against the enum values. You can eliminate the complexity of `isValidInput` and `userValue` by using `while (true)` and returning directly:

```
fun getUserChoice(): Choice {
    while (true) {
        println("Please enter one of the following:")
        for ((index, item) in Choice.values().withIndex()) {
            println("${index + 1} . $item")
        }
        val userInput = readLine().toString()
        println("You have chosen $userInput")
        try {
            return Choice.valueOf(userInput)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            println(ERROR_MESSAGE)
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have a list of relationships, `printResult` becomes very simple. We find a relationship that matches our two inputs. If none is found, indicated by null, we can presume it's a tie.

```
fun printResult(gameChoice: Choice, userChoice: Choice) {
    println("I have chosen $gameChoice")
    val relationship = Choice.relationships.firstOrNull {
        (it.winner == gameChoice && it.loser == userChoice) ||
                (it.loser == gameChoice && it.winner == userChoice)
    }
    when (relationship) {
        null -> println("It is a draw")
        else -> with (relationship) { println("$winner $means $loser. $winner wins!!") }
    }
}
```

Finally, your `getGameChoice` function doesn't make sense because it just returns its argument. You should move the randomization inside the function so it makes sense:

```
fun getGameChoice() = Choice.values().random()
```

The main function becomes:

```
fun main() {
    val gameChoice = getGameChoice()
    val userChoice = getUserChoice()
    printResult(gameChoice, userChoice)
}
```

Comment: *I can't think of a way to get the compiler to ensure we don't accidentally leave out a relationship.* - One option would be to use nested `switch` statements, but I think this option might be even better.

Comment: Exactly, unless you would encode the win/lose inside the statements in some other way, and have the else statement simply switch the two around, but then you would have a potential stackoverflow so... Not worth it.

Comment: Upon more thought, I still can't see how it could be done. Every choice has precisely two inferior choices that must be defined. I don't see a way to enforce matching two other choices to every choice or to ensure that there are no accidental redundancies.

Comment: You might want change the sequence of the arguments to Relationship. Compare `Relationship(Rock, Lizard, "crushes")` vs `Relationship(Rock, "crushes", Lizard)`. And maybe `Relationship` also to something else, I just haven't figured a better name yet.  Plus, the relationships should be in a map. `firstOrNull` is a linear search over in-memory data. It doesn't matter in this case, it's just generally not a nice appraoch, maps are better at this.

Comment: @ChristianHujer Yes, those would be good improvements.

Answer (score 2):

In these two scenarios:

1.

```
} else (ERROR_MESSAGE)
```

2. 

```
if (!isValidChoice) {
    ERROR_MESSAGE
}
```

No error message is actually printed. Simply writing the code `ERROR_MESSAGE` does not print it.

These should be:

1.

```
} else println(ERROR_MESSAGE)
```

2. 

```
if (!isValidChoice) {
    println(ERROR_MESSAGE)
}
```